# Are Topic message dequeued after they are consumed by topic subscriber?(AMQ 5.3.1)

Tags: memory-leaks, jms, messaging, activemq-classic

I have jms topic, which may have 0,1,2 subscribers (meaning that some of the subscribers may be down or stopped).
I have producer which constantly is sending messages to the topic and i can see that messages are enqueued in the topic, i see that there are subscribers, and i see that my consumers are receiving messages. But from the activemq web admin intefrace i see that no message is dequeued. Also From heapdump i saw that at the time passes messages in the topic are increasing, but the consumers are consuming them slower, and the producer is sending them faster. So after sometime i got outofmemory exception.

My question is if messages are not dequeued, does that mean that they are in the topic and the memory is increasing because of their count growing? How can i fix this?

A copy from the activemq admin intefrace:
Name        Number Of Consumers Messages Enqueued Messages Dequeued
TEST_TOPIC 1                    26490             0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the messages will be stored in the persistency store you have configured in your configuration file, but as long as:

- there is an active subscription to that kind of message
- there is a persistent subscription (consumer) to that kind of message.

If you have problems consuming your messages at the same (or higher) rate that you produce them, you have several possibilities:

- [flow control](http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html)
- [Pending Message Limit Strategy](http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html) (it lets you configure the maximum number of matched messages the broker will keep around for a consumer in addition to its prefetch buffer. Once this maximum is reached, as new messages come in, older messages are discarded)
- [Time to live](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQMessageProducer.html) of your messages. You basically set how long your messages will be valid, the broker will discard them when they reach that time to live.

In your case, I would put in place one of the 3 strategies mentioned above. I would personally go for the second one (Pending message limit strategy).

Comment: My producer is publishing ~10 messages per second. But The producer and activemq server are running on remote server which is around 3000km in distance from the consumer. Even i leave the onMessage(Message msg) method body empty the heap memory, even with slower rate, is still growing.

Comment: I set Pending MEssage Limit and prefetched size. But actually the problem was that messages were not AUTO_ACK and they were increasing in the consumer. I had to dig in the activemq code to understand that.